# how to run nfc demo sample

Tags: android, sdk, nfc

I'm trying to run the nfc demo sample from Android SDK in eclipse with the import error com.google cannot be resolved. I have the package Android 2.3.3 (API 10) complete installed, including the "Google API" and also the package of tools under linux 64

I followed these steps:

- 1 New Android project
- 2 Create project from existing sample
- 3 Build target selected: Android 2.3.3 API level 10
- 4 NFC demo selected
- 5 Finish

Changing project properties target to Google APIs don't fix the issue.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You might need these libraries:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

We plan on shipping them with the SDK at some point I believe. Sorry that this was not mentioned in the SDK documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add "guavalib.jar". You can do that by the following steps:
Right click on project NFCDemo->Build Path->configure build path->libraries->add external JARS->(browse to) android sdk->tools->select "guavalib.jar". Click on OK.
Then run the NFCDemo app.... its ready to go!